# Is it possible to allow access to Laravel API only with one API key?

Tags: php, laravel, api, api-key

I'm new to the Laravel API world. I want to make a simple Laravel application than returns some stuff in json format. I don't want it to be accessible to anyone with the url link though. I want to allow the access only by one API key. Is it possible? Or every user must have a unique key? And how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely possible. We do not know your application requirements, however if you wish only to return some stuff and therefore you have no need for identifying which user did what, there is no reason to go with key per user as another answer suggested.

For example, you can put your key in .env

```
API_KEY=yourkey
```

And then, simply add middleware to api routes, which will first check, if there is a proper ApiKey passed within the request.

You can pass your env variable to any config file and then call `config('yourConfigFile.apiKey')` anywhere in your app.

For some simple scenarios this approach is 100% sufficient. Take into consideration who will have access to this key and how it will be passed. If there will be one global key, and your api consumer will simply use ajax without proxing it via server, your api key will be exposed and everyone will be able to grab it and use it anywhere.

If that is the case, you can still avoid creating key per user – just specify list of allowed domains which can call your API and then check key. It all can be checked within middleware.

Like I said, know your requirements/use cases and then make a decision :-)

Comment: side note: don't use `env` outside of config files, if the config gets cached the `.env` file doesn't get loaded and `env` calls will return `null`

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I'm using Laravel as a back-end to a Vue front-end app. So I don't care which user did what, I just want to pass stuff from the DB to Vue in JSON format. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ShadyAlfred, if your Vue app in in the same domain, you do not need to play with api keys at all. Simply read about "same origin policy". Otherwise, just make a domain checker as I wrote above. While using api key and passing it from front-end via Vue, every user of your site will have a possibility to grab that key from requests and use it on his site.

Comment: No, they will be hosted on two different servers. Yeah, I will check the domain of the request in the middleware as you suggested. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

yes possible.

You have to have api_token field in users table and also add middleware in your api routes. api.php

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->string('api_token', 80)->after('password')
                        ->unique()
                        ->nullable()
                        ->default(null);
});
```

middleware in api routes (api.php):

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

You can define custom api guards for your api as well, for example if you have two tables called doctor and patient, you will have two tables and for both users you will be need unique api_token, you can define those custom api guards in your config/auth.php

see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication